# What does it mean when there are two plus-or-minus signs for a measurement?

Tags: distances, mass, units, event-horizon-telescope

As far as I know, the plus-or-minus sign is used to indicate the [statistical margin of error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign#In_statistics) of a measurement. But what does it mean when there are two plus-or-minus signs in the same measurement?

Some examples from Wikipedia:

- The mass of [M87*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87#Supermassive_black_hole) is given as `(6.5 ± 0.2stat ± 0.7sys) × 109 M☉` (as measured by the Event Horizon Telescope).
- The measured distance to [Sagittarius A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*) is given as `7860 ± 140 ± 40 pc`.

Comment: Look at the subscripts:  it's attribution of portions of the total error to different effects

Comment: Hm. So are the different portions additive? e.g. could you say that the distance to Sgr A* is 7860 ± 180 pc?

Answer (score 3):

The first error is due to the precision of the measurement, the second is an uncertainty associated with methodology used.